# Webpage save as mht file and retrieve again

Tags: powershell, mhtml

First, I'm trying to save a webpage as .mht file in powershell.
Afterwards, I need to be able to retrieve the content from that file again,
and have it stored in a `HtmlWebResponse` object, just as if the website would have been retrieved with the `Get-WebResponse` cmdlet.
Example:

```
$google = Get-WebResponse -Uri 'http://www.google.be'
$google.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                   BaseType                                                 
-------- -------- ----                   --------                                                 
True     False    HtmlWebResponseObject  Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject
```

I would need something like:

```
# Save content
Save-AsMht -Content $google -Path 'C:\temp\savedFile.mht'  

# Retrieve content
$google2 = Read-Mht -Path 'C:\temp\savedFile.mht'
```

With `$google2` being a `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject.HtmlWebResponseObject`

Comment: No, the correct method to have a *properly rendered web page* is to open it in the browser e.g. using InternetExplorer.Application object. [Example](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/95ce08b7-20cc-4ff8-9311-8aa5e6f81782/save-webpage-as-mhthtml-file-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell)

Comment: @wOxxOm When opening a saved (by Internet Explorer) `.mht` webpage with Internet Explorer, it is rendered perfectly. Is it possible to get a `HtmlWebResponseObject` from there?

Comment: I would recommend retrieving web pages the way @wOxxOm suggests as you will encounter issues with rendering,scripts,etc with pure powershell. You can easily serialize, save to file, and then recreate objects with the Export-CliXml and Import-CliXml commands.

Comment: @StephenP  Yes, for future webpages, I can use the serialization with Export-CliXml and Import-CliXml. However, the problem is that I have a number of webpages stored as .mht. Those webpages are currently not online anymore. So I have no choice but to start from those .mht files.

Comment: You can use the Invoke-WebRequest cmdlet and point the uri parameter to a file path which will get you a Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebResponseObject object from the mht.